# Meaning and usage of двушку-хрущевку

Tags: перевод

While reading a newspaper, I came across the word **двушку-хрущевку**, and had a question concerning it. The full sentence reads:

> квартплата за двушку-хрущевку — 2,5-4,5 тысячи в месяц

I looked up the word **хрущевкa**, and it said that it is one of those pre-fabricated concrete apartment buildings built during the time of Xрущев. And my guess is that the **двушку** refers to it being two bedrooms. I was wondering if there are any other common ways to refer to these type of buildings.

Comment: хрущёвка is most common

Comment: Also usually in such type of flat you have to go through living room to get into bedroom. That makes living room not so comfortable.

Comment: @DK. кухня в число комнат не входит. "bedroom with a separate kitchen" is a *однушка* or a *полуторка*.

Comment: @DK., ну это обычно студия.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not exactly `bedrooms`, just two rooms, `a living room + a bedroom` constitute а `двушка`

Just to clarify `хрущёвка` refers to the type of building, not to an apartment, but for convenience of brevity it all has been lumped into a single term which includes designation of both the type of an apartment and the type of building

Another way is too verbose and thus uncommon

`дом хрущёвской постройки`

or the complete term unpacked

`двухкомнатная квартира в доме хрущёвской постройки`

Another point is that if by `concrete` you mean `constructed of panels`, it's not the only type of `хрущёвкa` as there're brick-made `хрущёвки` as well